# Como insertar una nueva columna dependiendo de los elementos en común entre dos DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

tengo dos DataFrame, en uno de ellos se encuentra información de los productos solicitados a un negocio con el código de Material, descripción y número de documento del pedido, en el otro Dataframe cuento con la fecha. Entonces del segundo DataFrame debo tomar la fecha y llevarla al primer DataFrame como mostrare a continuación.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
            [2008489, 'Cereal', 4000002155], 
            [2008492, 'Galleta', 4000002157],
            [2008464, 'Yogurt', 4000002180], 
            [2008490, 'Leche', 4000002124])
           columns=['Material', 'Descripción', 'Doc.compr']
```

Y cuento con otro DataFrame algo similar donde se encuentra la fecha del pedido.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
            [2008489, 01.05.2021, 'Cereal', 4000002155],
            [2006520, 01.05.2021, 'Granola', 4000002155],
            [2006525, 01.05.2021, 'Frijol', 4000002155],
            [2008492, 15.05.2021,'Galleta', 4000002157],
            [2008464, 24.05.2021, 'Yogurt', 4000002180],
            [2008465, 24.05.2021,'Kumis', 4000002180],
            [2008490, 26.05.2021,'Leche', 4000002124])
           columns=['Material', 'Fecha', 'Descripción', 'Doc.compr']
```

Por ultimo lo que debo hacer es del DataFrame 2 tomar la fecha y llevarla al DataFrame 1 siempre y cuando coincida con el material y documento de compra, es decir, obtener algo asi:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
            [2008489, 01.05.2021, 'Cereal', 4000002155], 
            [2008492, 15.05.2021, 'Galleta', 4000002157],
            [2008464, 24.05.2021, 'Yogurt', 4000002180], 
            [2008490, 26.05.2021, 'Leche', 4000002124])
           columns=['Material', 'Fecha,'Descripción', 'Doc.compr']
```

Como pueden ver en el DataFrame 2 estan los mismos documentos de pedido pero contienen todos los materiales que incluyen el pedido, en este caso solo necesito los materiales que se encuentran en el 1, trate con:

```
df['Fecha'] = list('Si estoy' if x else "Tipo 2" for x in 
 df['Doc.compr.'].isin(df2[['Doc.compr.']))
```

Pero esto en cada lugar donde si se cumple la condición me esta agregando toda la columna fecha, lo cual no es correcto.

Comment: Es bastante sencillo pero... que has intentado?? Cual es el código que te causa problemas? y cual es el problema?

Comment: Ah claro, me falto decir que he intentado. Lo que he tratado de hacer es usar isin para buscar si los elementos de uno se encuentran en otro, pero el isin me devuelve True o False. Tambíen trate con la siguiente linea:    df['Fecha'] = list('df2['Fecha']' if x for x in df['Doc.compr.'].isin(df2['Doc.compr.']))*   Pero no me resulto lo que queria.

Comment: `isin` te devuelve una matriz de booleanos, para convertir eso en datos debes hacer `df[df['Doc.compr.'].isin(dfecha[['Doc.compr.']))]`

Comment: No entendi muy bien esa linea anterior, por otro lado me genera un error. Podrias explicarme por favor. Gracias.

Comment: ok, ahora hago una respuesta. Por mientras prueba con esto `df[df['Doc.compr'].isin(df2['Doc.compr'])]` y dime si es lo que quieres

Comment: La verdad no, esto solo me devuelve otro DataFrame idéntico pero no me lleva la columna de Fechas al primer DataFrame.

Comment: Bueno creo que lo correcto sería esto `df2[df2["Doc.compr"].isin(df["Doc.compr"])]["Fecha"]` Esta trae la fecha del df2 solo si `df["Doc.compr"]` está en `df2["Doc.compr"]`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130711/discussion-between-juan-esteban-and-christian).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder obtener datos de otro DataFrame debemos de hacer un filtrado de datos, lo cual se hace mediante esta sintaxis:

```py
df[<condicion>]
```

donde la `condicion` debe ser un valor booleano, por ejemplo `df["num"]<10` deuelve una serie de booleanos. Lo que tu quieres hacer es obtener los datos que coincidan en ambos DataFrames y para eso existe el método `isin()` que verifica si una lista de valores se encuentra en un DataFrame, lo que has hecho está casi correcto.

Para obtener la fecha del `df2` haremos el filtrado, donde la `condicion` será la sentencia `isin()` y  eligiremos la columna `fecha` como resultado del filtrado `df[<cndicion>][<columnas>]`

```py
fechas = df2[df2["Doc.compr"].isin(df["Doc.compr"])]["Fecha"]
print(fechas)
```

Esta es la condición que se necesita, sin embargo al probarla me di cuenta que devuelve todo el `df2` esto debido a que en el `df2` la columna `Doc.compr` hay valores que se repiten, pero lo que es único es la columna `Material`. Aquí tienes 2 opciones.

La primera opción es que cambies la condición de filtrado, que en vez de que lo hagas por `Doc.compr` lo hagas por `Material`. Esta opción no la recomiendo mucho ya que, aparte que no es lo que pides en la pregunta, muy seguramente no traerá los datos correctos.

La segunda opción es hacer el filtrado teniendo en cuenta los 2 campos, es decir obtener los valores que coincidan tanto en `Doc.compr` como en `Material`. Para esto solo elaboramos otra condición y listo.

```py
df["Fecha"] = df2[df2["Material"].isin(df["Material"]) & df2["Doc.compr"].isin(df["Doc.compr"])]["Fecha"]
print(df)
```

Esto debería de mostrarte las fechas correctas. Otra forma de hacerlo es haciendo un `merge` entre los DataFrames, pero creo que te sería un poco más complejo y confuso. Si no has entendido algo o tienes una duda hazmela saber :D

Comment: Genial, entendi todo, como decias ya estaba algo cerca pero no sabia como pasar de obtener los valores booleanos a los valores reales del DataFrame. Aunque extrañamente cuando lo probe en los DataFrame reales me resultaron unos cuantos NAN pero en general me sirvio demasiado. Muchas gracias.

Comment: De nada, puedes investigar más en la [documentación de pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html)